# Send data from GSM module to cloud server like firebase

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, iot

I am trying to search for anything to send my sensor data from Arduino + GSM SIM900A to a cloud server, preferably firebase. Does anyone know how can I achieve this operation to firebase or any other cloud database?